# How to fix json.decoder.JSONDecodeError when I use googletrans API?

Tags: python, pandas, google-translate, sentiment-analysis, vader

I am trying to translate a series of tweet from Italian into English. They are contained in a csv file so I extract them with pandas to compute the sentiment with Vader. Unfortunately, I get this error json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0).

I have tried both to remove the emoji from the tweet and to use a vpn as indicated on some other posts but it doesn't work.

```
def remove_emoji(text):
    return emoji.get_emoji_regexp().sub(u'', text)

def extract_emojis(str):
  return ''.join(c for c in str if c in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI)

def clean_emojis(text):
    toreturn = ""
    for c in text:
        if c not in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI:
            toreturn += c
    return toreturn

def sentiment_analyzer_scores(text, engl=True):
    if engl:
        translation = text
    else:
        try:
            emojis = extract_emojis(text) 
            text = clean_emojis(text)

            demoji.replace(text)
            text = remove_emoji(text)
            text = text.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')

            # translator= Translator(from_lang="Italian",to_lang="English")
            # translation = translator.translate(text)
            translation = translator.translate(text).text
            # print(translation)

        except Error as e:
            print(text)
            print(e)
            pass

    text = translation + emojis
    # print(text)
    score = analyser.polarity_scores(text)
    return score['compound']

def anl_tweets(lst, engl=True):
    sents = []
    id = 0
    for tweet_text in lst:
        try:
            sentiment = sentiment_analyzer_scores(tweet_text, engl)
            sents.append(sentiment)
            id = id + 1
            print("Sentiment del tweet n° %s = %s" % (id, sentiment))

        except Error as e:
            sents.append(0)
            print(e)
    return sents

#Main
translator = Translator()
analyser = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
file_name = 'file.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
print(df.shape)

# Calculate Sentiment and add column
df['tweet_sentiment'] = anl_tweets(df.tweet_text, False)
# Save the modifies
df.to_csv(file_name, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with emoji, Google has limitations on how many characters you can translate and when you reach that limit, Google API simply blocks you.

Read about the quota [here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/quotas)
Simple solution is to break your script into multiple chunks and use proxy server / different IP address.

Another option is  https://pypi.org/project/translate/
(I haven't tried it though)